# Changing the values of object.style.alignSelf

Tags: javascript, css

Let's say I have a function that changes the Align Self css property via JS.

### HTML

```
<img id= "arrow" src="/images/leftarrow.svg">
```

### CSS

```
.container {
    background-color: $white;
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 4px 1px black;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    visibility: visible;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
#arrow {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    align-self: flex-end;
    top: 50vh;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: $white;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

### JS

```
function reverseIcon () {
    arrow.style.alignSelf = "flex-start";
}

arrow.addEventListener("click", reverseIcon);
```

Javascript doesn't seem to change the align self property straight away. When I click, it does not change. I jumped into devTools to see what was wrong and it was applied when there was a change in the screen(?). I have no media queries. I tried this on 3 different browsers but AlignSelf doesn't seem to show up on the screen right away. It only actually changes as soon as I jump into devtools or like change the size of the screen. Anyone know why?

**Nevermind, Seems like only Chrome isn't responding to it. Still don't understand what part of this code isn't compatible with Chrome then

Comment: What has transform rotate to do with `alignSelf`? Nothing. Also with only the above... hard to tell. Create a [mcve]

Comment: Mentioned transform rotate because that was working the way it should be but alignSelf wasnt for some strange reason. I assumed I just miswrote something somewhere but only alignSelf seems to change AFTER there is a change in state of the screen..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the **alignSelf** property **gets applied** when you **change your screen** size?
Or is it just the default bahavior? In Dev-Tools, if you inspect, do you see the **style-attribute** at your image element? **If yes**, than it could be that your **#arrow selector overrides** it. If that's the case, I would try to **toggle between a class** where you can use the **!important** rule to **override** the property. Like so:

```
.flex-start{
align-self: flex-start !important; 
}
```

Comment: When I do inspect it, I can see in the style attribute that its added. But here's the thing!
When I press and it doesn't work, I jump into DevTools, then suddenly the style does get applied (hence the reason I mentioned when there is a change in state of the screen, if that makes sense). It doesn't work till I've actually hopped onto DevTools. the other funny thing is, when I press it again to make it return, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Also tried your solution. But doesnt seem to really fix this issue. Only chrome is having this issue. Safari and Mozilla both dont have any issues applying the code and actually show up. Chrome wont budge for some reason. Seems more like a compatibility issue at this point but I cant tell what part about this Chrome is refusing

Comment: mhh, sounds really weird. Sry idk what it could be